# guake with zsh doesn't start

Tags: bash, zsh, guake

I changed guake to use /bin/zsh from /bin/bash. now it doesnt start. by start, i mean that when  click the shortcut key, guake just pops up for a second, and then disappears. I changed the default interpreter back to bash, and it works. what is the problem?

As an aside, how can I make zsh the default <s>terminal</s> shell?

Comment: Remember that the full path of `zsh` in `/usr/bin/zsh`, whereas `bash`'s `/bin/bash`.

Comment: zsh seems to ship a /bin/zsh4.  Is that insufficient?

Comment: There is a `/bin/zsh` in Maverick, and I think also previous releases.

Comment: neither of /usr/bin/zsh or /bin/zsh work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symptoms you describe are a lot like the bugs http://pad.lv/360253 and http://pad.lv/625192 so I suggest you add some debugging information to the latter.  See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport for how to get a crash file to attach to the bug.

> As an aside, how can I make zsh the default terminal?

It's a shell, not a terminal.  But to change it just for your account, you want

```
chsh -s /bin/sh
```

and to change it for newly-added accounts, change `DSHELL` in `/etc/adduser.conf`.

Comment: thanks for the correction. Also, does it mean that I have to change the first line in all the scripts from #! /bin/bash to #! /bin/zsh ?

Comment: Uh, what are you trying to accomplish?  The instructions I gave are to make zsh the default shell when you log in or start a text terminal.

Comment: no, your answer was correct, It just struck me that there are some scripts that have the shebang, and just asked for clarification.

Comment: Scripts with no shebang are I believe run by `/bin/sh` which is a link to `dash` on Ubuntu.

Comment: @Kaustubh: Do not change the shebang line on any script. Bash and zsh have (slightly) different syntax, zsh can't execute a bash script or vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the same problem by running zsh in Terminal. This created new .zshrc file. So, I think, this problem caused by lack of .zshrc